# Haskell - simple constructor comparison (?) function

Tags: haskell

In my project I have created a data type, that can hold one of a few types of values:

```
data PhpValue = VoidValue | IntValue Integer | BoolValue Bool
```

What I wanted to do now, is to have a simple way of checking if two values of the `PhpValue` type are of the same constructor (correct me if I'm confused with the terminology here, but basically what I want to check if both are, for example, are `IntValue`, without caring about the particular value).

Here is a function I wrote for that:

```
sameConstructor :: PhpValue -> PhpValue -> Bool
sameConstructor VoidValue VoidValue = True
sameConstructor (IntValue _) (IntValue _) = True
sameConstructor (BoolValue _) (BoolValue _) = True
sameConstructor _ _ = False
```

This works as it should, but I don't really like it: if I add more constructors (like `FloatValue Float`) I am going to have to rewrite the function, and it will get bigger as my data definition gets bigger.

**The Question:** Is there a way of writing such a function, so that its implementation doesn't change when I add more constructors?

For the record: I don't want to change the `data` definition, I have enough Monads in the rest of my code as it is ;)

Comment: You should replace arguments you never use with `_`. So `sameConstructor sth els = False` can better be written as `sameCOnstructor _ _ = False` and so on. This makes the fact that you're not going to use those values clearer.

Comment: You can replace `(IntValue a)` and others with `(IntValue _)` as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at `Data.Data` and its `toConstr` function. This returns a representation of the constructor which can be compared for equality.

With an extension (you can put `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}` at the top of your module), you can have a `Data` instance derived for you automatically:

```
data PhpValue = VoidValue | IntValue Integer | BoolValue Bool 
              deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

You should then be able to use the `toConstr` function to compare by constructor.

Now the following will be true:

```
toConstr (BoolValue True) == toConstr (BoolValue False)
```

Using `on` from `Data.Function` you can now rewrite `sameConstructor` to:

```
sameConstructor = (==) `on` toConstr
```

This is the same as

```
sameConstructor l r = toConstr l == toConstr r
```

I think the version using `on` is easier to read at a glance.

Comment: That is all I asked for and some more, plus I don't have to change the  way the compiler is invoked. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is nice when you have simple types in your constructor arguments. If they contain something like `IOException`, GHC won't be able to derive it automatically anymore and writing the `Data` instance manually is annoying and more code than anything else.

Comment: Every parameterised type must also derive Data aswell for this to work. This can be complicated if a module doesn't expose their data constructors.

Answer (score 6):

This is known as the [expression problem](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2010/10/01/solving-the-expression-problem/) in Haskell and ML-family languages; there are a number of unsatisfactory solutions (including using `Data.Typeable` and abusing typeclasses, in Haskell) but no nice solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since the definition follows a regular format, you can use Template Haskell to automatically derive such a function for any datatype. I went ahead and wrote a [simple package](https://github.com/daig/data-constructors) for this since I wasn't fully satisfied with the existing solutions.

First, we define a class

```
class EqC a where
    eqConstr :: a -> a -> Bool
    default eqConstr :: Data a => a -> a -> Bool
    eqConstr = (==) `on` toConstr
```

and then a function `deriveEqC :: Name -> DecsQ` which will automatically generate instances for us.

The `default` is a [default signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=defaultsignatures#ghc-flag--XDefaultSignatures), and means that when the type is an instance of `Data` we can omit the definition of `eqConstr`, and fall back to Tikhon's implementation.

The benefit of Template Haskell is that it produces a more efficient function. We can write `$(deriveEqC ''PhpValue)` and get an instance that is exactly what we'd write by hand. Take a look at the generated core:

```
$fEqCPhpValue_$ceqConstr =
  \ ds ds1 ->
    case ds of _ { 
      VoidValue ->
        case ds1 of _ { 
          __DEFAULT -> False;
          VoidValue -> True
        };  
      IntValue ds2 ->
        case ds1 of _ { 
          __DEFAULT -> False;
          IntValue ds3 -> True
        };  
      BoolValue ds2 ->
        case ds1 of _ { 
          __DEFAULT -> False;
          BoolValue ds3 -> True
        }   
    }
```

In contrast, using `Data` introduces a good deal of extra indirection by reifying an explicit `Constr` for each argument before comparing them for equality:

```
eqConstrDefault =
  \ @ a $dData eta eta1 ->
    let {
      f
      f = toConstr $dData } in
    case f eta of _ { Constr ds ds1 ds2 ds3 ds4 ->
    case f eta1 of _ { Constr ds5 ds6 ds7 ds8 ds9 ->
    $fEqConstr_$c==1 ds ds5
    }
    }
```

(There's a lot of other bloat involved in computing `toConstr` that's not worth showing)

In practice this leads to the Template Haskell implementation being about twice as fast:

```
benchmarking EqC/TH
time                 6.906 ns   (6.896 ns .. 6.915 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.903 ns   (6.891 ns .. 6.919 ns)
std dev              45.20 ps   (32.80 ps .. 63.00 ps)

benchmarking EqC/Data
time                 14.80 ns   (14.77 ns .. 14.82 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 14.79 ns   (14.77 ns .. 14.81 ns)
std dev              60.17 ps   (43.12 ps .. 93.73 ps)
```

Comment: You may appreciate my rather absurd attempt at efficiency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45449225/1477667

Answer (score 2):

One popular alternative to `Data` is `Generic`. I think `Data` probably makes more sense in this context, but I figured it would make sense to add this just for completeness.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts #-}
module SameConstr where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Function (on)

class EqC a where
    eqConstr :: a -> a -> Bool
    default eqConstr :: (Generic a, GEqC (Rep a)) => a -> a -> Bool
    eqConstr = geqConstr `on` from

class GEqC f where
  geqConstr :: f p -> f p -> Bool
  {-# INLINE geqConstr #-}
  geqConstr _ _ = True

instance GEqC f => GEqC (M1 i c f) where
  {-# INLINE geqConstr #-}
  geqConstr (M1 x) (M1 y) = geqConstr x y

instance GEqC (K1 i c)
instance GEqC (f :*: g)
instance GEqC U1
instance GEqC V1

instance (GEqC f, GEqC g) => GEqC (f :+: g) where
  {-# INLINE geqConstr #-}
  geqConstr (L1 x) (L1 y) = geqConstr x y
  geqConstr (R1 x) (R1 y) = geqConstr x y
  geqConstr _ _ = False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any of the reasonable ways in the other answers, you can use a completely unsupported way that is guaranteed to be fast but not actually guaranteed to give correct results or even not to crash. Note that this will even be happy to try to compare functions, for which it will give utterly bogus results.

```
{-# language MagicHash, BangPatterns #-}

module DangerZone where

import GHC.Exts (Int (..), dataToTag#)
import Data.Function (on)

{-# INLINE getTag #-}
getTag :: a -> Int
getTag !a = I# (dataToTag a)

sameConstr :: a -> a -> Bool
sameConstr = (==) `on` getTag
```

One other problem (arguably) is that this peers through newtypes. So if you have

```
newtype Foo a = Foo (Maybe a)
```

then

```
sameConstr (Foo (Just 3)) (Foo Nothing) == False
```

even though they're built with the `Foo` constructor. You can work around this by using a bit of the machinery in `GHC.Generics`, but without the runtime cost associated with using unoptimized generics. This gets pretty hairy!

```
{-# language MagicHash, BangPatterns, TypeFamilies, DataKinds,
             ScopedTypeVariables, DefaultSignatures #-}

import Data.Proxy (Proxy (..))
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Function (on)
import GHC.Exts (Int (..), dataToTag#)

--Define getTag as above

class EqC a where
  eqConstr :: a -> a -> Bool
  default eqConstr :: forall i q r s nt f.
                      ( Generic a
                      , Rep a ~ M1 i ('MetaData q r s nt) f
                      , GNT nt)
                   => a -> a -> Bool
  eqConstr = genEqConstr

-- This is separated out to work around a bug in GHC 8.0
genEqConstr :: forall a i q r s nt f.
                      ( Generic a
                      , Rep a ~ M1 i ('MetaData q r s nt) f
                      , GNT nt)
                   => a -> a -> Bool
genEqConstr = (==) `on` modGetTag (Proxy :: Proxy nt)

class GNT (x :: Bool) where
  modGetTag :: proxy x -> a -> Int

instance GNT 'True where
  modGetTag _ _ = 0

instance GNT 'False where
  modGetTag _ a = getTag a
```

The key idea here is that we look at the type-level metadata associated with the generic representation of the type to determine whether or not it's a newtype. If it is, we report its "tag" as `0`; otherwise we use its actual tag.

Answer (score -1):

In your special case you can use the `Show` magic of the compiler:

```
data PhpValue = VoidValue | IntValue Integer | BoolValue Bool deriving Show

sameConstructor v1 v2 = cs v1 == cs v2 where 
   cs = takeWhile (/= ' ') . show
```

Of course depending on the string representation generated by the compiler is very close to a hack...

Comment: That this works in this special case has not so much to do with the compiler used (as the derived `Show` instance is mandated by the Haskell Report), but with the fact that `PhpValue` has *less than* two infix constructors! Think about `data Foo a = a :+ a | a :- a deriving Show` for a bit...

Comment: Of course, as soon as you add something fancy like infix constructors, `sameConstructor` will fall over.