# Test if a value matches a constructor

Tags: haskell

Say I have a data type like so:

```
data NumCol = Empty |
              Single Int |
              Pair Int Int |
              Lots [Int]
```

Now I wish to filter out the elements matching a given constructor from a `[NumCol]`. I can write it for, say, `Pair`:

```
get_pairs :: [NumCol] -> [NumCol]
get_pairs = filter is_pair
    where is_pair (Pair _ _) = True
          is_pair _ = False
```

This works, but it's not generic. I have to write a separate function for `is_single`, `is_lots`, etc.

I wish instead I could write:

```
get_pairs = filter (== Pair)
```

But this only works for type constructors that take no arguments (i.e. `Empty`).

So the question is, how can I write a function that takes a value and a constructor, and returns whether the value matches the constructor?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

At least `get_pairs` itself can be defined relatively simply by using a list comprehension to filter instead:

```
get_pairs xs = [x | x@Pair {} <- xs]
```

For a more general solution of matching constructors, you can use prisms from the `lens` package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Extras (is)

data NumCol = Empty |
              Single Int |
              Pair Int Int |
              Lots [Int]

-- Uses Template Haskell to create the Prisms _Empty, _Single, _Pair and _Lots
-- corresponding to your constructors
makePrisms ''NumCol

get_pairs :: [NumCol] -> [NumCol]
get_pairs = filter (is _Pair)
```

Comment: Ah, list-filter-via-pattern-matching. This is one of the very few virtues of keeping `fail` around.

Comment: @DanBurton Well, technically that doesn't use `fail`, as list comprehensions have a separately described desugaring from `do` notation. And I'm sure they'd rather change the `do` one to use `mzero` than delete it outright.

Comment: What exactly is happening in the first function `get_pairs` What does the syntax `{}` mean? I've only seen curly braces in "record syntax"

Comment: @lsund It *is* record syntax, just without listing any fields to match, which means it only checks the constructor given. As a special case, this can be used even if the datatype is not defined with record syntax. Also the `x@` part binds the whole "record" to `x`.

Comment: Clever, I didn't know you could match on the data constructor that way!

Answer (score 28):

Tags of tagged unions ought to be first-class values, and with a wee bit of effort, they are.

Jiggery-pokery alert:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures,
    TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, FlexibleInstances,
    PatternSynonyms
#-}
```

Step one: define type-level versions of the tags.

```
data TagType = EmptyTag | SingleTag | PairTag | LotsTag
```

Step two: define value-level witnesses for the representability of the type-level tags. Richard Eisenberg's Singletons library will do this for you. I mean something like this:

```
data Tag :: TagType -> * where
  EmptyT   :: Tag EmptyTag
  SingleT  :: Tag SingleTag
  PairT    :: Tag PairTag
  LotsT    :: Tag LotsTag
```

And now we can say what stuff we expect to find associated with a given tag.

```
type family Stuff (t :: TagType) :: * where
  Stuff EmptyTag   = ()
  Stuff SingleTag  = Int
  Stuff PairTag    = (Int, Int)
  Stuff LotsTag    = [Int]
```

So we can refactor the type you first thought of

```
data NumCol :: * where
  (:&) :: Tag t -> Stuff t -> NumCol
```

and use `PatternSynonyms` to recover the behaviour you had in mind:

```
pattern Empty        = EmptyT   :&  ()
pattern Single  i    = SingleT  :&  i
pattern Pair    i j  = PairT    :&  (i, j)
pattern Lots    is   = LotsT    :&  is
```

So what's happened is that each constructor for `NumCol` has turned into a tag indexed by the kind of tag it's for. That is, constructor tags now live separately from the rest of the data, synchronized by a common index which ensures that the stuff associated with a tag matches the tag itself.

But we can talk about tags alone.

```
data Ex :: (k -> *) -> * where  -- wish I could say newtype here
  Witness :: p x -> Ex p
```

Now, `Ex Tag`, is the type of "runtime tags with a type level counterpart". It has an `Eq` instance

```
instance Eq (Ex Tag) where
  Witness EmptyT   ==  Witness EmptyT   = True
  Witness SingleT  ==  Witness SingleT  = True
  Witness PairT    ==  Witness PairT    = True
  Witness LotsT    ==  Witness LotsT    = True
  _                ==  _                = False
```

Moreover, we can easily extract the tag of a `NumCol`.

```
numColTag :: NumCol -> Ex Tag
numColTag (n :& _) = Witness n
```

And that allows us to match your specification.

```
filter ((Witness PairT ==) . numColTag) :: [NumCol] -> [NumCol]
```

Which raises the question of whether your specification is actually what you need. The point is that detecting a tag entitles you an expectation of that tag's stuff. The output type `[NumCol]` doesn't do justice to the fact that you know you have just the pairs.

How might you tighten the type of your function and still deliver it?

Comment: Is your brain available as a download? I would very much like to be able to think of this kind of thing myself.

Comment: My brain is remarkably unavailable, even to me at times. But all I've done here (and perhaps I should have said so) is the Haskell-fake of a standard issue "Sigma type". That is, a type of dependent pairs, where the type of the second component depends on the value of the first. The Sigma type encoding of tagged unions as the pair of a tag enumeration and a whatever-else-the-tag-says-you-need is quite standard (but still, annoyingly, not the way datatypes work in Agda/Idris). Porting to Haskell takes the singleton construction, also standard, also annoying.

Answer (score 8):

One approach is to use `DataTypeable` and the `Data.Data` module. This approach relies on two autogenerated typeclass instances that carry metadata about the type for you: `Typeable` and `Data`. You can derive them with `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}`:

```
data NumCol = Empty |
          Single Int |
          Pair Int Int |
          Lots [Int] deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

Now we have a `toConstr` function which, given a value, gives us a representation of its constructor:

```
toConstr :: Data a => a -> Constr
```

This makes it easy to [compare two terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112733/haskell-simple-constructor-comparison-function/10112843) just by their constructors. The only remaining problem is that we need a value to compare against when we define our predicate! We can always just create a dummy value with `undefined`, but that's a bit ugly:

```
is_pair x = toConstr x == toConstr (Pair undefined undefined)
```

So the final thing we'll do is define a handy little class that automates this. The basic idea is to call `toConstr` on non-function values and recurse on any functions by first passing in `undefined`.

```
class Constrable a where
  constr :: a -> Constr

instance Data a => Constrable a where
  constr = toConstr

instance Constrable a => Constrable (b -> a) where
  constr f = constr (f undefined)
```

This relies on `FlexibleInstance`, `OverlappingInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`, so it might be a bit evil, but, using the (in)famous eyeball theorem, it should be fine. Unless you add more instances or try to use it with something that isn't a constructor. Then it might blow up. Violently. No promises.

Finally, with the evil neatly contained, we can write an "equal by constructor" operator:

```
(=|=) :: (Data a, Constrable b) => a -> b -> Bool
e =|= c = toConstr e == constr c
```

(The `=|=` operator is a bit of a mnemonic, because constructors are syntactically defined with a `|`.)

Now you can write almost exactly what you wanted!

```
filter (=|= Pair)
```

Also, maybe you'd want to turn off the monomorphism restriction. In fact, here's the list of extensions I enabled that you can just use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, FlexibleInstances, NoMonomorphismRestriction, OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
```

Yeah, it's a lot. But that's what I'm willing to sacrifice for the cause. Of not writing extra `undefined`s.

Honestly, if you don't mind relying on `lens` (but boy is that dependency a doozy), you should just go with the prism approach. The only thing to recommend mine is that you get to use the amusingly named `Data.Data.Data` class.

Comment: Two things: (1) You can use the same `Pair {}` syntax that I used to match with in my answer to construct a value with all arguments undefined. (2) Putting in `undefined`s by either method won't work if the constructor has any strict fields.

Comment: Maybe it's just the kind of [things](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-dynamic) I've been writing lately, but no, that doesn't exactly look like a lot of extensions to me.  Even UndecidableInstances has lost its scariness, now. :)

Comment: @Jules: I was being *a bit* facetious with that comment :).

Comment: You might want to restrict the type of `(=|=)` to `forall a. a -> a -> Bool`. Two constructors of different types should _never_ be equal, but as the Data.Data documentation says, "Note that equality on constructors with different types may not work -- i.e. the constructors for False and Nothing may compare equal." See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Constr

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the GHC guide to using a more precise version of `OverlappingInstances` with Safe Haskell: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell/NewOverlappingInstances

Comment: Actually, w/r/t my comment on restricting the type of `(=|=)`, I now realize that that would exclude the use case of the OP, where you use only the constructor on one side and a full value on the other (those have different types!)