# Comparing values by their constructors

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have a data type defined like this:

```hs
data Token
  = Literal Integer
  | Operator String
  | Separator Char
  | Identifier String
```

If I have a value of type `Token`, is there an elegant way to check if its type constructor is e.g. `Operator`? Or even more: is there a way to check if two values of type `Token` are instances of the same constructor?

I could obviously create functions:

```hs
isOperator :: Token -> Bool
isOperator (Operator _) = True
isOperator _ = False

haveSameConstructor :: Token -> Token -> Bool
haveSameConstructor (Literal _) (Literal _) = True
haveSameConstructor (Operator _) (Operator _) = True
haveSameConstructor (Separator _) (Separator _) = True
haveSameConstructor (Identifier _) (Identifier _) = True
haveSameConstructor _ = False
```

However, this is really verbose, especially if the type has more constructors. Or I could use `case ... of` but using it always when I need to compare the constructors seems repetitive to me. Is there some clever solution? E.g. something like a function `isKindOf Operator token`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112733/haskell-simple-constructor-comparison-function this is what you are looking for, I guess. `Data.Data` lets you make clean comparisons.

Comment: Depending on why you need to make such checks, maybe a GADT is a possibility.

Comment: As suggested, you can use `Data.Data` to do this in a general way, but I can't stop wondering if you really need to compare constructors in this way, neglecting their contents. Usually reducing rich information to a single boolean leads to bad code. There might be an XY problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [user1984](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7755665/user1984) posting a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112733/haskell-simple-constructor-comparison-function) I have been able to figure out a solution:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data

data Token
  = Literal Integer
  | Operator String
  | Separator Char
  | Identifier String deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)

sameConstructor :: Token -> Token -> Bool
sameConstructor a b = toConstr a == toConstr b
```

It doesn't let me check if a value is an instance of a particular constructor but at least I can replace it by comparing two values like this `sameConstructor token (Operator "")`.